# WooCommerce - How to delete custom field line with CR and LF removed

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, metadata, orders

I have custom field data on my WooCommerce orders which I manually add once the order has been completed. How can I delete a line from the custom field including the carriage return and line feed?

My custom field called "SERIAL_NUM" looks like this:

```
644765050200
644765032001
644765020502
644765070103
644765010044
```

Here is my current implementation of the code:

```
$orders = wc_get_orders(array(
    'customer' => $current_owner_id,
    'limit' => -1,
));

foreach ($orders as $order)
{
    $order_id_sender = $order->get_id();

    $serial_numbers = get_post_meta($order_id_sender, 'SERIAL_NUM');
    $new_meta_value = str_replace($serial_number_transfer, '', $serial_numbers);

    // Update the post meta with the new value
    update_post_meta($order_id_sender, 'SERIAL_NUM', $new_meta_value);
}
```

However, when I run this code, if serial `644765032001` matches via the `$serial_number_transfer` variable, the list in the custom field ends up looking like this (with an empty line):

```
644765050200

644765020502
644765070103
644765010044
```

Instead, I want it to look like this:

```
644765050200
644765020502
644765070103
644765010044
```

How can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

**SOLUTION**

```
foreach ($orders as $order)
{
    $order_id_sender = $order->get_id();
    $serial_numbers = get_post_meta($order_id_sender, 'SERIAL_NUM');

    // while updating the post meta with the new value, search for multiple occurrences of "\r\n" and replace it with "\r\n"
    update_post_meta($order_id_sender, 'SERIAL_NUM', preg_replace("/[\r?\n]+/", "\r\n", str_replace($serial_number_transfer, '', $serial_numbers[0])));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Important pro tip: WordPress's postmeta, usermeta, and option values can contain arbitrary data structures, not just strings.**

Your meta_value contains a data structure -- a list of text strings. You are representing that list as a single text string. The point is, it's a list.

So, handle it that way.  [Explode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) it to an array, change it, then [implode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) it back to a string before you store it. Like this:

```php
/* Get the meta value */
$serial_num_string = get_post_meta( $order_id_sender, 'SERIAL_NUM' );
/* Clean out consecutive newlines, returns, etc. */
$serial_num_string = preg_replace( "/[\r\n]+/", "\n", $serial_num_string );
/* Make an array of the lines in the string. */
$serial_nums = explode ("\n", $serial_num_string );

/* Now you can operate on that array, and you don't have to use regex
 * code (which is good to avoid if you can) to mess with the string. */

/* array_diff($a, $b) is usesful. It removes items in $b from $a */
$serial_nums = array_diff( $serial_nums, array( $serial_number_transfer ) );

/* Store the updated array back in the postmeta. */
update_post_meta($order_id_sender, 'SERIAL_NUM', implode( "\n", $serial_nums ) );
```

You can make any changes you need to make to the $serial_numbers array when you have it in hand. Then, implode() it back to a string and save it.

At the beginning I mentioned WordPress can store (almost) any data structure into postmeta.

If you handled your `SERIAL_NUM` postmeta values that way, you would **store the array of strings directly**. Your code would look like this. No exploding or imploding or cleaning up extraneous newlines or any of that jazz. Your code. Shorter is better.

```php
$serial_nums = get_post_meta( $order_id_sender, 'SERIAL_NUM' );
$serial_nums = array_diff( $serial_nums, array( $serial_number_transfer ) );
update_post_meta( $order_id_sender, 'SERIAL_NUM', $serial_nums );
```